# Cooking Dry noodles without them being soggy

Tags: chinese-cuisine, noodles, egg-noodles

Could I get some tips on how to cook like or similar to Sharwoods Dry Noodles since when I cook, strain, wash and add them to the wok for cooking they always seem to come out soggy and sloppy. I've tried cooking them less but it doesn't really help too much.

So any tips to make them better?

Answer (score 1):

Soak in boiling water while cooking the rest of the stir fry, drain and lob 'em in for the the last 30 seconds so they get coated with sauce and don't get too soggy.